# PHP - Cross Reference Dropdowns

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, cross-reference

I have a form that I need to build that provides the user with 3 drop down menus. The first one is manufacturer. The user selects what manufacturer they want and then they click the "Submit" button. A query is generated and it puts that manufacturers model numbers in the second drop down. Again, the user selects the model and then clicks submit again. This then provides the user with a third drop down(really shouldn't be a drop down but it works) that displays the model number for a compatible replacement unit. I hope all this makes sense.

The problem is that when I select and submit the values the page reloads and it replaces my selection with the first selection in the database. I need it to be consistent throughout the drop downs and display the selected values.

I'm not the best programmer but I've gotten this far and I need to figure it out!

Thanks and here is the code I'm using at the moment. All the data is stored in one table with 4 columns(id, model, name, aomodel)

```
<html> <head> <title>Demo Drop-Down Box</title> </head> <body>
<?php mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); mysql_select_db ("test1");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry) 
{ print $key . ": " . $entry . "<br>"; } ?>

<form method="post"> <?php $sql = "SELECT distinct name from test1.crossref"; $result =        mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='name'>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<option      value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";

$sql1 = "SELECT model from test1.crossref where name = '$entry'"; $result1 =    mysql_query($sql1);
echo "<select name='model'>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { echo "    <option value='" . $row['model'] . "'>" . $row['model'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";

$sql2 = "SELECT aomodel from test1.crossref where model = '$entry'"; $result2 =     mysql_query($sql2);
echo "<select name='aomodel'>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { echo "    <option value='" . $row['aomodel'] . "'>" . $row['aomodel'] . "</option>"; }
echo "</select>";

?>
<br /> <input type="submit"/> </select> </body> </html>
```

Comment: What you need is AJAX, that way the user won't even need to click submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of three things:

1) Do this in Javascript 
2) Send parameters for all items selected when the page reloads
3) Send the user to another page with the parameters

Probably Javascript is best for what you're trying to do, and then POST or GET the items on a final submit.

Comment: Are your lists populated with all of the data on page load and you just want to preselect items as they change dropdowns, or are you wanting the lists to update with different data based on selections?

Comment: I would like to use PHP just because I can half understand it.

The only part that is loaded initially is the first drop down which contains the manufacturer name. From there the other values are determined by what you selected. I feel like a moron trying to explain this because it seems like I can't.